# Prove that $a, b, c, a+b, a+c, b+c, a+b+c$ can all be the same colour.

Tags: number-theory, functions

> Suppose that every integer is coloured one of three colours. Prove that there exist distinct integers $a, b, c$ such that all of the following are the same colour: $a, b, c, a+b, a+c, b+c, a+b+c.$

I initially thought of splitting the integers into $3$ sets, one of which has infinitely many colours. Obviously, if two of the sets are empty, then there exist such integers. However, I wasn't sure how to ascertain that there exist such integers when more than one set has arbitrarily many elements.

An alternative approach I thought of involved showing that $\exists a, b, c\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that for any function $f: \mathbb{Z}\to \{0, 1, 2\},f(a) = f(b) = f(c) = f(a+b)=f(a+c)=f(b+c)=f(a+b+c),$

but I'm not sure how to show this.

Comment: It's probably an overkill, but it follows from Hindman's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_set

Comment: @MartinR no it does not. My question asks if the pattern also applies for arbitrarily many colours.

Comment: The idea uses ultrafilters often. You should try to look on Hindman's theorem. And This post was a duplicate , you can find the solution pdf in other post on mse.

Comment: After googling a little while, I found this theorem: "Van der Waerden's theorem states that for any given positive integers r and k, there is some number N such that if the integers {1, 2, ..., N} are colored, each with one of r different colors, then there are at least k integers in arithmetic progression whose elements are of the same color. " https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waerden%27s_theorem